# Vue filter in v-for

Tags: vuejs2

Hi I am pretty new to VueJS and have started working on a very simple API request. I have an object that looks like this:

```
posts: [
  text: "String",
  choices: {"1":"Yes","2":"No"}
]
```

Coming from angular, this seems very straightforward. I would just use a filter to convert choices to an object and loop over it. However, I ran into a problem. When I attempt to use the filter 'log' or 'json' in the v-for, they don't work.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <li v-for="(post,index) in posts | log">
      <ul>
        {{ post.text | log }}
        {{ post.choices | json }}
        <li v-for="(value,key) in post.choices | json">
          {{value}} {{key}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {HTTP} from './main';
export default {
  filters: {
    json: function (value) {
      return JSON.parse(value)
    },
    log: function (value) {
      console.log(value)
    }
  },
  props: [
    'apiKey'
  ],
  data: () => ({
    posts: [],
    post: [],
    errors: []
  }),

  created() {
    HTTP.get('questions', { headers: { 'Api-Key': this.apiKey} })
    .then(response => {
      this.posts = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Then no data shows up, however they work fine in the mustache template. Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

**tl;dr**

works:

```
{{ post.choices | json }}
```

does not work:

```
<li v-for="(value,key) in post.choices | json">
```

Any work around? I can't use computed properties because this is a "sub-object" of an array and computed properties don't work that way, unless I am mistaken?

Comment: Your `post.choices` is already a JS object, there is no need to run `JSON.parse` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need to use `JSON.parse`, since the `choices` key refers to a valid JS object. Unless you have made a mistake, and that the `choices` key refers to a string.

Anyway, if you want to parse `post.choice` into a valid JS object, you can simply pass it into a custom function which returns the parsed JSON to `v-for`, for example:

```
<li v-for="(value,key) in postChoicesJson(post.choice)">
    {{value}} {{key}}
</li>
```

And then declare a method for that:

```
postChoicesJson: function(obj) {
    return JSON.parse(obj);
}
```

**Note:** Your DOM is invalid, because `<li>` elements **must be a direct child of a `<ul>` or an `<ol>` element**.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the <li> tags issue.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add a filter to a `v-for` directive.

Just parse the data before setting the `posts` data property:

```
HTTP.get('questions', { headers: { 'Api-Key': this.apiKey} })
.then(response => {
  let posts = response.data;
  post.forEach(p => p.choices = JSON.parse(p.choices));
  this.posts = posts;
})
```

Comment: Thanks you! While this does work, I was looking for something that followed a similar format as Terry's answer. +1